# Strange behaviour of array.includes returning always false for string 'sku'

Tags: javascript

I'm facing strange behaviour of array.includes functionality.
My job is to check if variable feedProduct has all required fields.

```
function hasAllRequiredFields(requiredFields, feedProduct) {
    
    // Prepare array for adding missing fields
    let missing_required = [];
    
    // Print all fields and there type (only for easier debugging)
    console.log(feedProduct);
    console.log(typeof feedProduct);
    feedProduct.forEach(fp => {
        console.log(fp)
        console.log(typeof fp)
    })
    
    // Check if feedProduct array contains all required fields
    console.log('')
    console.log('CHECK IF ALL REQUIRED FIELDS ARE PRESENT')
    requiredFields.forEach(wf => {
        console.log(wf);
        console.log(typeof wf);
        if (!feedProduct.includes(wf)) {
            missing_required.push(wf);
        }
    })
    
    console.log('')
    console.log('')
    console.log('Missing')
    console.log(missing_required)
    
    return missing_required;
}
```

And the result is so strange. As you can see i'm searching for string 'sku' type of string in array FeedProduct, which includes string 'sku' of type of String, but `feedProduct.includes(wf)` returns false

[image: sku missing]

I've also tried the same logic with indexOf and result is the same. If I copy/paste this code in Developer tools, then result will be true and no fields will be missing

Can some please point me what else should I check or do, so my code will be working properly. If you need any additional informations, please let me know and I will provide. Thank you

**UPDATE

function is called in some other function, like this

```
let hasRequiredFields = hasAllRequiredFields(preparedMappingFields.storeFeedMustHaveFields, header);
```

result for `console.log(feedProduct[0], requiredFields[0], feedProduct[0] === requiredFields[0]);` is following

sku sku false

** UPDATE TWO

```
console.log(requiredFields[0].split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)))
console.log(feedProduct[0].split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)))

Log 1:
[ 115, 107, 117 ]
Log 2:
[ 65279, 115, 107, 117 ]
```

Comment: can you show how you are calling your function ?

Comment: can you also show what `console.log(feedProduct[0], requiredFields[0], feedProduct[0] === requiredFields[0]);` logs

Comment: @NickParsons Updated, check question

Comment: @Valor_ looks like your two strings are different (even though they visually look the same), can you check what `console.log(requiredFields[0].split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)))` gives and what `console.log(feedProduct[0].split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0)))` gives?

Comment: You are right! They are not the same! Check updated question :)

Comment: So you should trim() all values before comparing them

Comment: @Valor_ your `feedProduct` array contains an `sku` comprising a *zero width no-break space* character (65279) followed by an `'s'` and so the two strings are treated as different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that the two strings that look like `"sku"` aren't really equal: the one in the `feedProduct` array contains an invisible character in front of it.

That character, `U+FEFF`, also known as the Byte Order Mark is often put at the beginning of Unicode files to indicate the correct byte order (endianness).

I don't know where your data is coming from, but that character was left in it during parsing.

The best way would be to save the file with the data *without BOM*, or, if that's not possible, remove it just after reading from the file.

To remove this character, you can use the following code:

```js
const outputString = inputString.replace(/^\uFEFF/, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your are simply looking for the difference between two arrays, so you could as well just do this...

```js
const rf = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

const fp = ['foo', 'baz']

const difference = rf.filter( x => !fp.includes(x))

console.log(difference)
```

If you would want to get the intersection you would want to do this...

```js
const rf = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

const fp = ['foo', 'baz']

const intersection = rf.filter( x => fp.includes(x))

console.log(intersection)
```

Comment: Yes, it's maybe more practically approach, but problem still remains. I get this product fields from CSV file, there for I'm assuming that maybe something is wrong with encoding or something

Comment: @Valor_, oh ok, that is a different story than. Can't you just check what your getting back from the parsed CSV file?

Comment: I have updated my question. There you will see those console.log, and strings are not the same :(

Answer (score 1):

The function works.(Although it could be optimised)

```js
function hasAllRequiredFields(requiredFields, feedProduct) {

  // Prepare array for adding missing fields
  let missing_required = [];

  // Print all fields and there type (only for easier debugging)
  console.log(feedProduct);
  console.log(typeof feedProduct);
  feedProduct.forEach(fp => {
    console.log(fp)
    console.log(typeof fp)
  })

  // Check if feedProduct array contains all required fields
  console.log('')
  console.log('CHECK IF ALL REQUIRED FIELDS ARE PRESENT')
  requiredFields.forEach(wf => {
    console.log(wf);
    console.log(typeof wf);
    if (!feedProduct.includes(wf)) {
      missing_required.push(wf);
    }
  })

  console.log('')
  console.log('')
  console.log('Missing')
  console.log(missing_required)

  return missing_required;
}
var feedProductData = [
  'sku', 'kategorija_proizvoda', 'naziv_proizvoda',
  'proizvodjac', 'specifikacija', 'proizvod_url',
  'cena', 'slika_url', 'dostupnost_proizvoda'
];
var requiredFieldData = ['sku', 'required_and_missed'];
hasAllRequiredFields(requiredFieldData, feedProductData);
```

The only reason I can see is that your `sku` !== `sku`. Adding trim should solve the issue.

Optimized code

```js
function hasAllRequiredFieldsUpdated(requiredFieldData, feedProductData) {
  return requiredFieldData.filter(x => !feedProductData.includes(x))
}
var feedProductData = [
  'sku', 'kategorija_proizvoda', 'naziv_proizvoda',
  'proizvodjac', 'specifikacija', 'proizvod_url',
  'cena', 'slika_url', 'dostupnost_proizvoda'
];
var requiredFieldData = ['sku', 'required_and_missed'];
var missingFields = hasAllRequiredFieldsUpdated(requiredFieldData, feedProductData);
console.log(missingFields);
```